# ie bho IDispatchEx::Invoke failure

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, atl, bho

Good day, I have problem with browser helper object for internet explorer. I need to call back to my c++ code from injected js code from page, so I must export some c++ methods to js code. I have found method via `IDispatchEx::Invoke`, but this method constantly failing for some sites.

```
void __stdcall CEventSink::DocumentComplete(IDispatch *pObject, VARIANT *pvarUrl)
{
    if(pObject)
    {
        IServiceProvider *pSp = NULL;
        if(SUCCEEDED(pObject->QueryInterface(IID_IServiceProvider, (void**)&pSp)))
        {
            IWebBrowser2 *browser = NULL;
            if(SUCCEEDED(pObject->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&browser)))
            {
            IDispatch *disp = NULL;
            if(SUCCEEDED(browser->get_Document(&disp)))
            {
                IHTMLDocument2 *doc = NULL;
                if(SUCCEEDED(disp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void**)&doc)))
                {
                    IHTMLWindow2 *w = NULL;
                    if(SUCCEEDED(doc->get_parentWindow(&w)))
                    {
                        CComPtr<IDispatchEx> dispxWnd;
                        if(local_data.tabs[(ptr_type)browser].bho)
                        {
                            if(SUCCEEDED(w->QueryInterface( &dispxWnd )))
                            {
                                CComBSTR propName( L"cbx" );
                                DISPID dispid;
                                if(SUCCEEDED ( dispxWnd->GetDispID( propName, fdexNameEnsure, &dispid )))
                                {
                                    CComVariant varMyBho( (IDispatch*)local_data.tabs[(ptr_type)browser].bho );
                                    DISPID dummy[] = {DISPID_PROPERTYPUT};
                                    DISPPARAMS params;
                                    params.cArgs = 1;
                                    params.cNamedArgs = 0;
                                    params.rgvarg = &varMyBho;
                                    params.rgdispidNamedArgs = NULL;
                                    if(FAILED( dispxWnd->Invoke( dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUTREF, &params, NULL, NULL, NULL )))
                                    {
                                        MessageBoxA(NULL, "failed to dispxWnd->Invoke", "", MB_OK);
                                        //TODO: handle error
                                    }
                                }
```

It's failing on call `if(FAILED( dispxWnd->Invoke( dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUTREF, &params, NULL, NULL, NULL )))`, but only for some sites, tee-links.com for example. `local_data.tabs[(ptr_type)browser].bho` is stored pointer to instance of class with implemented interfaces. as suggested by first comment a have added some code to retrieve some info about error, quick and dirty

```
HRESULT hr = dispxWnd->Invoke( dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUTREF, &params, NULL, NULL, NULL );
                                                if(FAILED(hr))
                                                {
                                                    _com_error err(hr);
                                                    LPCTSTR msg = err.ErrorMessage();
                                                    char errnum[32];
                                                    _snprintf(errnum, 31, "%x", hr);
                                                    MessageBox(NULL, msg, to_utf16(errnum).c_str(), MB_OK);
```

so we have error message something like "group member not found", i have russian os installed so can't say exactly, and error code 80020003

Comment: This is "it did not work" error reporting.  You'll need to improve it so you *know* why it failed.  HRESULT hr = dispxWnd->Invoke(..);  if (FAILED(hr)) { ... }

Comment: i have russian os installed, sense of message something like "group member not found", hex error code 80020003

Comment: Have you created a type library for your module?  [Here is a blog post](http://jeffcode.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-to-create-activex-control-that.html) I wrote a long time ago that explains how to go the other way you may find it helpful.

Comment: i think without type library it wont work at all, in my case it's do not work only fof few sites, for 90% it works as expected. thank you for post, i have nothing against atl, and it's look a bit hard to implement for me, so i will keep this for later use if not solve my problem with current qrchitecture of bho.

Comment: Error code is `0x80020003` `DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND` "Member not found" and it indicates that callee does not have a `putref_` method for this `DISPID` (no `putref_cbx` there).

Comment: so, as i understand it's can't be fixed as it's not a bug ?, maybe here exists some alternative methods to export c++ interface to js code inside page ?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a dynamic DISPID with `IDispatchEx::GetDispID` which is supposed to work with `IDispatchEx::InvokeEx`, but then you're providing it to `IDispatch::Invoke`, which is supposed to work with the static DISPIDs returned by `IDIspatch::GetIDsOfNames`.

---

PS: I also find the following line interesting:

```
CComVariant varMyBho( (IDispatch*)local_data.tabs[(ptr_type)browser].bho );
```

Are these really all `IDispatch` pointers?  Or are they `IUnknown` pointers?  If the latter, then you must `QueryInterface`.

Comment: thank you for reply, i will check it, and yes, all of .bho members are same and IDispatch is implemented

Comment: i can post simplified sample of my bho with this problematic logic implemented

Comment: checked, same result, i have uploaded simplified sample of this bho (with IDispatchEx::Invoke) http://sss.chaoslab.ru/code_.7z

Comment: Note that implementing `IDispatch` and being a pointer to `IDispatch` are two different things.  If the `bho` field doesn't explicitly point to an `IDispatch` or a derived interface, then you must `QueryInterface` for it (assuming it points to an `IUnknown` or derived).

Comment: At the very least, you must `static_cast<IDispatch*>(local_data.tabs[(ptr_type)browser].bho)` (or cast to `Ibho*`), since the `bho` field is a `Cbho *`, to get an `IDispatch`.

Comment: But, did you try `InvokeEx` instead of `Invoke`?

Comment: yes, i have checked with InvokeEx, it's a bit old sample which is cleaned from lot's of actual programm code, currently i checking your suggestions

Comment: same result with static_cast<>, works for most sites, does not for tee-links.com

Comment: Ok then, this problem is solved.  Failing for a particular site is another problem, you'll have to debug your javascript.  Perhaps when you try to inject with `execScript`, there's no `<script>` element in the page yet, so you might have to create one to ensure a running scripting engine in the page.

Comment: no, i mean problem not with js, the problem is that on some sites Invoke or InvokeEx as described upper, you can check for example on tee-links.com

Comment: with all this changes behaviour are same as with my initial code. also this problematic sites have some limitations, do not know how to say correctly, i have warning in internal ie debugger about inaccessible api and page targeted to document mode (i do not know what this means).

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that in your question, although it was there all along.  Although these changes improve your code, they're not resolving your problem.  I think you must debug that at the javascript level.  Comparing your code to the one in [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sky96ah7(VS.94).aspx) shows a difference in the way "property put" is invoked.

Comment: thank you for suggestion, but now we have not anymore time for this method, switched to another less proper architecture, just have not time anymore